# MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen addsubview iOS8

Tags: ios

I want to add custom control,and in small view  player.view add subview it works well.And in fullscreen it doesn't work.
I use the code:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
{
     window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]          
}
```

to find the view.
How can i find the player's view to add the custom control  in iOS8？

Comment: do you want to add custom control in mpmovieplayercontroller?

Comment: I find another way to solve this。I add the custom control view to the player's view.And in fullscreen  I add the player's view to new UIViewController.In small view only add the player's view.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not easy that you add your custom control in movieplayer view this way:

```
[self.moviePlayer.view addSubview:self.movieControls];
```

or you can try this way :
Please see this full code if it works it just add one view to mpmoveplayercontrolelr

playerViewController is MPMoviePlayerViewController object and self.vwtest  is simple UIView

```
self.playerViewController=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"]];
self.playerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle =MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.vwtest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, 40)];
[self.vwtest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

[self.playerViewController.view addSubview:self.vwtest];
[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.playerViewController];
[self.playerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

Thanks.

Comment: I want add the custom controls in not only fullscreen also the small view.Thanks